# Tags "Erotica" and "Sex": Merge or synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Both [erotica](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erotica) and [sex](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) seem to cover roughly the same domain of writing. Perhaps they should be merged or else be added as synonyms?

Comment: Yes, individual questions for merge/synonym proposals are better than big lists.  (Makes the voting clearer.)  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio. Will remove the P.S from the question.
(To anyone who was wondering, the P.S read:
To suggest merging/synonyms, I should individually post questions, right? (I hope I am not spamming))

Comment: @PraveshParekh - Changes are also available to all in the [change history](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/posts/788/revisions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Erotica* is a genre of writing, while *sex* can cover individual sex scenes within any type of story. They are related, but not the same. *Sex* is a subset of *erotica*, so I don't think they should be merged.

I would suggest changing *sex* to *sex-scene* to make it clearer, or removing the *sex* tag altogether.

Comment: Changing sex to sex-scene makes sense.